# How to change IO() into [String] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am making a frame that print a character frame around a character as I show below.

This is example of frame. Example to understand what I actual frame is and What i am want from all these function right, left, up and down:

[image]

`a` is list of string that is `A`.

```
Main> showMatDownAttach '@' a
  aaaaa  
 a     a 
 a     a 
 aaaaaaa 
 a     a 
 a     a 
 a     a 
@@@@@@@@@

Main> showMatDownAttach '@' a
  aaaaa  
 a     a 
 a     a 
 aaaaaaa 
 a     a 
 a     a 
 a     a 
@@@@@@@@@
```

I also have for right and left. Now I want to make a function that can combine all of them in one function. How I can do this?

```
a = ["  aaaaa  "," a     a "," a     a "," aaaaaaa "," a     a "," a     a "," a     a "] 

--badar = putStr( concat (map (++ "\n")(letter 'a')))

--showMat ::  Char -> IO()
--showMat ch = putStr (concat ( map(++ "\n") (letter 'a')))


replicateIt :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
replicateIt x ls=take x (cycle ls)


--repeatIt :: Int -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
repeatIt num []=[]
repeatIt num (x:sx)= replicateIt num [x]:(repeatIt num sx)

hStretchChar :: Int  -> Char  -> String 
hStretchChar i ch = replicate i ch

hStretchString :: Int -> String -> String 
hStretchString i sts = concat ( map ( hStretchChar i) sts)

hStretchListOfString :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
hStretchListOfString i stlist = map (hStretchString i ) stlist

vStretchString :: Int -> String -> String
vStretchString i str = concat (replicate i (str ++ "\n"))

vStretchListOfString :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
vStretchListOfString  i strList = map (vStretchString i) strList


stretch :: Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
stretch i j strList = vStretchListOfString i (hStretchListOfString  j strList)

showMat' :: [String] -> IO()
showMat' strList = putStr (concat  (stretch 1 1 strList))

--Left Attach Character
leftattach :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
leftattach a strlist =  map ( a: ) strlist 

showMatCharAttachLeft :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
showMatCharAttachLeft a strList = putStr (concat  (stretch 1 1 ( leftattach a strList)))


charToString :: Char -> String
charToString a = a:[]

--Right Attach Character
rightattach :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
rightattach a strlist = map (++(charToString a)) strlist

showMatCharAttachRight :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
showMatCharAttachRight a strList = putStr (concat  (stretch 1 1 ( rightattach a strList)))

--Up Attach Character
upattach :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
upattach a strList = take (length (head strList)) (cycle (charToString a)) : strList

showMatUpAttach :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
showMatUpAttach a strList = putStr (concat (stretch 1 1 (upattach a strList)))


--Down Attach Character
downattach :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
downattach a strList = strList ++ listOfCharTolistOfString (take (length (head strList)) (cycle (charToString a)))

showMatDownAttach :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
showMatDownAttach a strList = putStr (concat (stretch 1 1 (downattach a strList))) 
--test0 a strList = listOfCharTolistOfString (take (length (head strList)) (cycle (charToString a)))

listOfCharTolistOfString :: [Char] -> [String]
listOfCharTolistOfString a = a:[]
```

Comment: What is the type of the function you're trying to write?

Comment: I am facing problem on *list* as `showMatDownAttach` get [String]  .
I am not good in english to explain but the code I hope you will understand what actual problem is. I hope you will understand my problem in this line. 
`list x ab = (showMatUpAttach x ((showMatDownAttach x ab)))`

Comment: @ChrisMartin can you tell me how to convert IO() -> [String] this is my problem?

Comment: That's impossible. There is very little you can do with a value of type `IO ()`. I think your mistake is that `showMatDownAttach` should typed as `Char -> [String] -> String`, not `Char -> [String] -> IO()`, and it should not include `putStr`. In other words, you should return the String, not print it. Avoid involving `IO` for as long as possible.

Comment: @ChrisMartin i checked the type of `putStr` this just return `IO()` then how I can write `String`.

Comment: I mean you should do this: `showMatUpAttach :: Char -> [String] -> String`; `showMatUpAttach a strList = concat (stretch 1 1 (upattach a strList))`

Comment: I'm using `putStr` a purpose. I think you will understand properly if you check my code on gist . Can you please view . https://gist.github.com/badarshahzad/3108ac7cffacaaa5d7781268f78ca88f

Comment: Please include all relevant code *here*. You can edit the question.

Comment: @ChrisMartin then i will face another problem that will be `\n` that I am using for attach with a list of string. This `putStr` actually helping me for `\n` for new line.

Comment: Ok I am editing again

Comment: *How* do you want to combine these Strings? What output do you want your program to produce?

Comment: I added the image for your view i want a frame like in picture mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IO ()` is a very opaque type; there isn't much you can do with it, and there isn't any meaningful way to convert it to `[String]`. Once you're in `IO`, you can't get out of it.

Generally in Haskell you write most of your code without using `IO`. Here's a solution to the problem to demonstrate what I mean. Notice that all of the "frame" code is defined with pure functions, and `IO` doesn't get introduced until `main` at the very end.

```
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import Data.List (repeat)

frame1 :: a -> [a] -> [a]
frame1 f xs = [f] ++ xs ++ [f]

frame2 :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
frame2 f grid = frame1 edge $ frame1 f <$> grid
  where edge = take (width grid + 2) $ repeat f

width :: [[a]] -> Int
width [] = 0
width (x:_) = length x

a :: [[Char]]
a = [ "  aaaaa  "
    , " a     a "
    , " a     a "
    , " aaaaaaa "
    , " a     a "
    , " a     a "
    , " a     a "
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = traverse_ putStrLn $ foldr frame2 a "* &"
```

Output:

```
***************
*             *
* &&&&&&&&&&& *
* &  aaaaa  & *
* & a     a & *
* & a     a & *
* & aaaaaaa & *
* & a     a & *
* & a     a & *
* & a     a & *
* &&&&&&&&&&& *
*             *
***************
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `IO ()` encapsulates all side-effects and is not just about console output. So pedantically there is no way to "change `IO ()` to `[String]`"

With that said, I believe [`System.Posix.Redirect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-posix-redirect-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Redirect.html) is what you are looking for. You just want to call `showMatDownAttach` to capture `stdout` to get the `[String]` you want.

A quick Google search reveals a couple more packages to do this as well:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-capture
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently

Now doing this is not very idiomatic Haskell and if you have access to `showMatDownAttach` you'll want to change it to something like what https://stackoverflow.com/a/40701235/111021 suggests. But since you ask this question I believe you already considered that and somehow that's not an option.

Comment: The closest you could get with this approach would be to convert `IO ()` to `IO [String]`, right? Not `IO ()` to `[String]` as requested.

Comment: @ChrisMartin While I believe my answer "more closely" answered the actual question asked (i.e. "what he probably actually wanted), what you said is totally true as well. The "real" answer to the literal question is basically, stated in your answer's starting sentence.